# How can PHP application keep data in memory?

Tags: java, php, spring

I have previously developed Java web applications (Spring, Spring Boot) where I keep a lot of data cached in memory to greatly increase the efficiency and number of simultaneous users that can be supported, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how a PHP application can achieve the same?

Is there a global way of doing this, or is the best equivalent using session variables?

Comment: Keep in mind that sessions are memory from one request to another for the same user. You can not use session to store cache for multiple users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is single-paged language (if we are talking about WEB). 
Look at this http://php.find-info.ru/php/016/ch20lev1sec5.html and this http://www.slideshare.net/laruence/the-php-life-cycle

If you need to keep a lot of data cached in memory at real time (like without making query in DB every time (every request)), you need to use some memory-based storage that will keeps persistent connection in your code.

Also, be carefully when you will use a lot of data in php variables, garbage collector working good but only for small-time requests. Look at `unset()` expression, for force cleanup heap.

Sorry for english :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your requirement. If I were you I would have prefer REDIS which is a deal breaker for real time concurrent database

- An empty instance of redis uses ~ 1MB of memory.
- 1 Million small Keys -> String Value pairs use ~ 100MB of memory.
- 1 Million Keys -> Hash value, representing an object with 5 fields,
  use ~ 200 MB of memory.(You can have 1 million simultaneous user for minimum 200 Mb)

The following can be your use case

- Real-time publish/subscribe notification systems
- Real-time analytics backends
- Task queues and job systems
- High score leaderboards

Answer (score 2):

You can create your custom cache class and use it (singleton class may be another solution).